# How to migrate DataFrame in Java API to Spark 2's Datasets?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark code which uses Dataframes, it was developed using Spark 1.6.1 where Dataframes were part of the sql package.

Now the project has moved to Spark 2.1.0 and Dataframes are no longer available.
As specified in the Spark website: `Dataframes are Datasets of rows`. So now the convention is to use datasets.

My previous code looked like this:

```
List<Row> normalizeDataset = ...//Some function 
DataFrame df =  sqlContext.createDataFrame(normalizeDataset, schema);
```

Is there any clean convention to move this instantiation of Dataframe into Dataset - Is there a clean and fast way yo migrate this and the following pieces of code into Spark 2 or I need to revisit my entire project?

Comment: according to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#migration-guide : "Java API users must replace DataFrame with Dataset<Row>"

Comment: you can continue using Dataframes.. actually in same cases (e.g. complex nested objects) you pretty much have to stay with dataframes